# Linq Collection Sorting

Tags: c#, console

I need to sort countries in this collection using LINQ:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        class Country
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Population { get; set; }

            public Country(string name, int population)
            {
                Name = name;
                Population = population;
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Country[] countryCollection = 
            { 
                new Country("Afghanistan", 34656032),
                new Country("Austria", 8857960),
                new Country("Brazil", 210147125),
                new Country("Denmark", 5789957),
                new Country("Russia", 144526636),
                new Country("China", 1403500365),
                new Country("Turkey", 80810525),
                new Country("Serbia", 7001444),
                new Country("Iraq", 37202572),
                new Country("San Marino", 33344) 
            };
        }
    }
}
```

It should be sorted by population and printed that way.

Comment: Did you try googling for "linq sort"?  That brought me to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/sorting-data.  The example they show using the `Length` property of a `string`, but you could use the `Name` or `Population` properties of your `Country`s

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't accept Population as a parameter. Compiler says it doesn't exist in current context when I code it this way.

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Country> countryCollection = new List<Country>() {
                                        new Country("Afghanistan",34656032),
                                        new Country("Austria", 8857960),
                                        new Country("Brazil", 210147125),
                                        new Country("Denmark", 5789957),
                                        new Country("Russia", 144526636),
                                        new Country("China", 1403500365),
                                        new Country("Turkey", 80810525),
                                        new Country("Serbia", 7001444),
                                        new Country("Iraq", 37202572),
                                        new Country("San Marino", 33344) };

        var OrderedCountries = countryCollection.OrderByDescending(x => x.Population).ToList();

        foreach (var country in OrderedCountries)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"The country {country.Name} has {country.Population} people");
        }

    }
}

public class Country
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Population { get; set; }


    public Country(string name, int population)
    {
        Name = name;
        Population = population;
    }

}
```

Comment: You could also use the LINQ syntax giving you `var orderCountries = from country in countryCollection orderby country.Name select country;` (which will sort by country name, ascending)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list or if you want to maintain an array you can use a delegate to anonymous method:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Country[] countryCollection = {
                new Country("Afghanistan", 34656032),
                new Country("Austria", 8857960),
                new Country("Brazil", 210147125),
                new Country("Denmark", 5789957),
                new Country("Russia", 144526636),
                new Country("China", 1403500365),
                new Country("Turkey", 80810525),
                new Country("Serbia", 7001444),
                new Country("Iraq", 37202572),
                new Country("San Marino", 33344)
            };

            Array.Sort(countryCollection, delegate(Country country1, Country country2) {
                return country1.Population.CompareTo(country2.Population);
            });

            foreach (Country country in countryCollection) Console.WriteLine("Country name: " + country.Name + " Population: " + country.Population);
            Console.ReadKey();        

        }
```

See http://www.csharp-examples.net/sort-array/ for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the array into a List, order it by population, and then convert it back into an array.

```
countryCollection = countryCollection.ToList().OrderBy(x => x.Population).ToArray();
```

Or if you want to order it by descending population instead:

```
countryCollection = countryCollection.ToList().OrderByDescending(x => x.Population).ToArray();
```